# Cardinality of unnumerable set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In the last class my professor asked us a question, which is:

> If a set $X$ is uncountable and $Y$ is a countable set, then is $X\setminus Y$ countable or uncountable?

What I did was to think of the set $\mathbb{R}$ and subtract from it the set of $\mathbb{N}$. Since the set $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{N}$ numerable, the set $\mathbb{R}$ is still uncountable because you cannot have injectivity but I am not sure about this answer, can someone give me a hint or tell me if my reasoning is correct please?

Comment: Hint: $X = Y \cup (X \setminus Y)$ and $Y, X\setminus Y$ are disjoint. What happens if you assume that $X \setminus Y$ is countable?

Comment: If $X\setminus Y$ are disjoint and countable I will have a empty set, right? @DominikKutek

Comment: What would be an empty set? I think I don't understand. What I meant, if you assume that $X \setminus Y$ is countable, then $X$ is an union of two countable sets (namely $Y$ and $X \setminus Y$). Why is this a contradiction with the assumption that $X$ is uncountable?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why is a contradiction @DominikKutek

Comment: Somehow I've misread the question and thought that $Y$ is a subset. Anyway you have $X \subset Y \cup (X \setminus Y)$. If both $Y$ and $X\setminus Y$ are countable then their sum is countable, too, hence $X$ as a subset of countable set is countable (by countable I mean finite or bijective with $\mathbb N$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X\setminus Y$ is countable or finite. Since $X=(X\setminus Y)\cup (X\cap Y)$ and $X\cap Y$ is countable or finite as a subset of a countable set $Y$, $X$ would be a (disjoint) union of two countable or finite sets, hence at most countable, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you but I have a doubt. I didn't understand this part "would be a union of two countable or finite sets, hence at most countable, a contradiction.". Could you please explain me that part, thank you. @markvs

Comment: What is it exactly that you do not understand? The fact that $X$ is the union of two (disjoint) subsets $X\setminus Y$ and $Y\cap X$? Or the fact that the union of two (disjoint) at most countable subsets is at most countable?

Comment: When you say "a union of two countable or finite sets, hence at most countable, a contradiction.". Why the union is a contradiction? @markvs

Comment: The contradiction with your assumption that $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: Hehe, for a moment I was lost. Thank you very much.